# Новое сообщение - внизу, а старое - вверху

Tags: php, html

Есть код. Для вывода массива использую `mysql_fetch_array`, при этом сообщения выводятся так: самое новое вверху. Как сделать, чтоб самое новое сообщение выводилось внизу, а старое - вверху?

```
$tmp      = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM private_messages WHERE poluchatel='$user_email' and author='$other_user_email' or poluchatel='$other_user_email' and author='$user_email' ORDER BY id DESC", $db);
$messages = mysql_fetch_array($tmp);

if (!empty($messages['id'])) {
    do {
        $author = $messages['author'];

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$author'", $db);
        $author = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        $author_id           = $author['id'];
        $author_small_avatar = $author['small_avatar'];
        $author_last_name    = $author['last_name'];
        $author_name         = $author['name'];
        $messages_id         = $messages['id'];
        $messages_date       = $messages['date'];
        $messages_text       = $messages['text'];

        echo "
        <div class='message'>
            <a href='page.php?id=$author_id'>
                <img class='small_avatar' width='90' height='90' alt='Автор' src='$author_small_avatar'>
            </a>
            <div class='avtor-bar'>
                <div class='user-name-fild'>
                    <a class='user-name-font' href='page.php?id=$author_id'>$author_name $author_last_name</a> 
                </div>
                <div class='delite'>
                    <a href='private_drop_post.php?id=$messages_id'><img alt='Удалить' src='images/close.png'></a>
                </div>
                <div class='data'>
                    Дата: $messages_date
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='message-fild'>
                $messages_text
            </div>
        </div>
        ";
    } while ($messages = mysql_fetch_array($tmp));
} else {
    echo "Сообщений нет";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это же просто:

```
ORDER BY `date` desc
```

вместо

```
ORDER BY `id` desc
```

И еще непонятно, зачем использовать do { ... } while();

Можно же так:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($tmp)) {
    //Тут вывод
}
```

Comment: Что-то не работоет, может у меня руки кривые можете скинуть готовый код ?

Comment: @Kirpich643, **ORDER BY `id` DESC**  - означает "**СОРТИРОВАТЬ ПО `id` В_ОБРАТНОМ_ПОРЯДКЕ**". Если дату, которая была внесена при добавлении записи, вы со временем не изменяли, то достаточно просто убрать из запроса эту сортировку или изменить на **ORDER BY id ASC**. Если же даты менялись, но надо ориентироваться на них, то вместо сортировки по id-шнику, надо сортировать по полю с датами, т.е.

    ... ORDER BY `date` DESC ... // начиная с самой старой даты
    // или
    ... ORDER BY `date` ASC ... // начиная с самой свежей даты

Comment: отлично спасибо !!!